# VMwareの「仮想マシンを開くときにエラーが発生しました：ホストまたはゲストOSのファイルにアクセス中にエラーが発生しました」

Tags: windows-10, vmware

タイトルの通りです。
安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方という本を勉強し始めたのですが、
CR-ROMに入っていたWASBOOKというファイルをVMwareで起動したところ「仮想マシンを開くときにエラーが発生しました：ホストまたはゲストOSのファイルにアクセス中にエラーが発生しました」というエラーが発生します。

使っているのは、Windows10, VMware Workstation 12 Playerです。

原因がわかるかたいたら教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

すみません。自己解決しました。zipファイルが圧縮されたままでした。